# How would I enforce at-least one in many optional properties for a TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript

I want to declare an interface for objects which may have either property 'a' or 'b'

```
interface myInterface {
    a ?: string;
    b ?: string;
}
```

makes both a and b optional. I want something like

```
interface myInterface {
    a|b ?: string;
}
```

(Edit1) Extended case

```
interface myInterface 
{ 
    mustHaveProp1 : number;
    a|b : string;
    mustHaveProp2 : string;
    b|d|e : number;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with an interface, you can do it with unions. The idea is to generate a union where we each union constituent has the same properties as the original type, but one property is required, so for `myInterface` we need something like: `{ a: string, b?: string } | { a?: string, b: string }`.

The above union is also (mostly) equivalent to the following intersection `myInterface & ({ a : string } | { b: string }`. (If we apply the distributive property between `&` and `|` we would get `(myInterface & { a: string }) | ((myInterface & { b: string })`, and since in each intersection a  property appears as both optional and required, the required wins out).

The big question then becomes how to create this union starting from `myInterface` without having to write it out explicitly. To do this, we can use a mapped type to take each property from an original type an create each member constituent and then index into the type to get the union of all of these new types. We can then just intersect with the original type:

```
interface myInterface {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
}

type OneProp<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: Record<P, T[P]>
}[keyof T]

type RequireAtLeastOne<T> = T & OneProp<T>

let o1: RequireAtLeastOne<myInterface> = {} // err no properties
let o2: RequireAtLeastOne<myInterface> = { a: "" } // a present, ok
let o3: RequireAtLeastOne<myInterface> = { b: "" } // b present, ok
let o4: RequireAtLeastOne<myInterface> = { a: "", b: "" } // a and b present, ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=81&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZZOAfgC5kBnMKUAcwG5TyAjG+xl9kgF9SpMOgAOKAPIgIABSgB7cQB4AKgD5kAXkIdkAbTnJQyANYR0imMjUBdALQ8AShASKoAExVyANLaM7DVJBAwsrG3sREjFJZFcARwBXYCgIAEEwABkIOAYZCHUtXTVkADJkAoVlIuiAGwgwZEUARlpElLTMnLywApUMbEhYRAhiwkFkAHop5GgoZBBFZHElSSgwYAg6UgamxQAmdohk1Izs3PzZAawcEaRxggpaACIX5EmZihW0ughwfyKMy7RrNADMx1OXQuvX6gzueDGOkIyE4r3en1mnB+23+YEBwJIe2aABZIZ1zj0roV4cNEY9nsg3v40UyMdNZnAKCBPKicX8Ac1CUA)

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood, but this seems too specific to the base case specified in the question. Would this work for extensions such as
`
interface myInterface {
mustHaveProp1 : number;
  a|b : string;
  mustHaveProp2 : string;
  b|d|e : number;
}
`
?
I will include this in the question.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike The explanation is based on the example in the question but the  types `OneProp` and `RequireAtLeastOne` will for for any `T`

Comment: I will try to play around with OneProp to see if I can get it to do what I want. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike If you have any issues with it let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

type IModal = { content: string; content_object?: undefined } |
              { content_object: object; content?: undefined }

Comment: Please write proper comment in your code about what you did and why you did, how it helps?